# How to add image in div.Innerhtml asp c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I want to add image to div, but `innerHtml` overrides it. How I need to achieve this? This is what I have for now:

```
Image ThumbImg = new Image();
ThumbImg.ImageUrl = ImgUrl; 

HtmlGenericControl divContent = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
divContent.Controls.Add(ThumbImg);
divContent.InnerHtml = Desc;
```

If I move `divContent.Controls.Add(ThumbImg);` line to the end, then it adds an image, but to the end of content and I want image to be in beginning of the content.

Comment: What is in "Desc"? If it is just a string could you add the image markup to it?

Comment: Instead of adding image in divContent, you should add Image in Desc content using '<img>' tag. It may help you.

Comment: "Desc" is a string. How can I add image to "Desc" then?

Comment: you can add it like this. See my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add "img" tag into Desc. Then set it in div's innerhtml.

```
Desc=Desc+ "<img src=" + ImgUrl + " />";
divContent.InnerHtml = Desc;
```

else

```
Image img = new Image();
img.ImageUrl = ImgUrl;
divContent.Append(img);
divContent.Append(Desc);
```

Comment: There's no function called Append.

Answer (score 2):

Use this to show image in Div

div.Style("background-image") = Page.ResolveUrl("~/Images/xyz.JPG")

Comment: Good approach. I would do like this `div.Style.Add("background-image", Page.ResolveUrl("~/Images/xyz.JPG"));`

Answer (score 1):

When you set `InnerHtml` you overwrite all Controls you added (as you found out).

Solution: add another control, such as a [LiteralControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.literalcontrol.aspx) where you put in the text.

```
Image ThumbImg = new Image();
ThumbImg.ImageUrl = ImgUrl; 

HtmlGenericControl divContent = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
divContent.Controls.Add(ThumbImg);
LiteralControl lit = new LiteralControl();
lit.Text = Desc;
divContent.Controls.Add(lit);
```

Or, as an alternative, use the [Label](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label.aspx) control. Difference: Label uses escaping before showing your text, LiteralControl doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You can add it like this.

```
Desc +=  "<img id=\"img1\" src="+ ImgUrl + " />";
divContent.InnerHtml = Desc;
```

Comment: `<img>` has a self closing tag. Otherwise solution is working, but you placed your answer later then @Hiral.

Comment: yes you are right @Morpheus. Thanks for your positive response.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but would this work:

```
divContent.InnerHtml += Desc;
```